# preg_match to match substring of three numbers consecutively?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, expression

I have a string `$text_arr="101104105106109111112113114116117120122123124"`
fairly big string

If i want to split three numbers from them like `101,104,105` and store them in `$array` .What should i do?

I tried doing this:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{3}$/',"$text_arr",$array);
```

Comment: you have to remove the $ from your expression, check my answer below

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is with [`preg_split()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$result = preg_split('/(\d{3})/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6RpTsD), or the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 101
    [1] => 104
    [2] => 105
    [3] => 106
    [4] => 109
    [5] => 111
    [6] => 112
    [7] => 113
    [8] => 114
    [9] => 116
    [10] => 117
    [11] => 120
    [12] => 122
    [13] => 123
    [14] => 124
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I have a similar array that i have to split based upon capital like "JimCaseyAlexShawn" ??

Comment: @Aditya Use the exact same line as above, but change the regex to `/([A-Z][a-z]+)/`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem For the given task, that is indeed true (and I should have thought of that). However, for the "split based on a capital" secondary question (see second comment on this answer) a regex is required - and that kind of validates this approach. You are are fundamentally correct though and you have a +1 from me.

Comment: @DaveRandom: cheers, and I really should pay more attention to follow-up questions in comments before I go and leave comments like the one above, that make me sound like a bit of a pedantic, know-it-all, twat :P +1 right back at you :)

Answer (score 2):

Though you *could* use a regular expression for this, it *might* be more performant to use a simple, standard function:

```
$groups = str_split($numbers, 3);//returns array you want
```

[Read all about it here](https://www.php.net/str_split)

Comment: I am getting the result like this: Array ( [0] =>  [1] => 101 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => 104 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => 105 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => 106 ) Array ( [0] => 109 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => 111 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => 112 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => 113 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => 114 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => 116 ) Array ( [0] => 117 )

Comment: @Aditya: I'm not, `str_split('123456789123456789',3);` works just fine. Check your input string, or set-up a pastebin or codepad, so we can see what you're doing

Comment: @Aditya: you're welcome, but would you mind awfully accepting DaveRandom's answer? his answer (in combination with his comments) are the most complete answer here, and he did make an effort :)

Answer (score 1):

**You have to remove the ends with $** from your expression, it is causing to return only one result

try like this

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{3}/', $text_arr, $array);
```

check this working [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CjCdnl)

Answer (score 1):

Choose this simplest code

```
<?php
    $string = "101104105106109111112113114116117120122123124";
    $parts = str_split($string, 3);
    $res=implode(',',$parts);
    echo($res);
?>
```