# Splitting string array based upon digits in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

I have a string

```
 $str = "101WE3P-1An Electrically-Small104TU5A-3,Signal-Interference Duplexers Gomez-GarciaRobertoTU5A-3-01"
```

I want to split this string by the numbers, eg:"101WE3P-1An.... "should be first element, "104TUA..." should be second element?

Somebody wrote me the following code in [my previous question *preg_match to match substring of three numbers consecutively?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14100965/367456) some little minutes ago:

```
$result = preg_split('/^\d{3}$/', $page, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Baseline is i want to match three digited number followed by any no of capitals, followed by anything including \t ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what **exactly** should be the result of `$str` after extract? It's not clear for me.. (too much `...`)

Comment: split it into $str[0] and $str[1]..

Comment: That's not the question. Let be simple. Take `$str="a b c d"`. If you want to split this string by space, it means you want `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. Right? So what do you want **at the end** ?

Comment: Not by space. i want to split by three digit no followed by capital letter followed by anything..

Comment: `/^\d{3}$/` => `/\d{3}/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell `preg_split()` to split at any point in the string which is followed by three digits by using a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
$str = "101WE3P-1An Electrically-Small104TU5A-3,Signal-Interference Duplexers Gomez-GarciaRobertoTU5A-3-01";
$result = preg_split('/(?=\d{3})/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

var_export($result);
```

Gives the following array:

```
array (
  0 => '101WE3P-1An Electrically-Small',
  1 => '104TU5A-3,Signal-Interference Duplexers Gomez-GarciaRobertoTU5A-3-01',
)
```

The `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag is used because the very start of the string is also a point where there are three digits, so an empty split happens here.  We could alter the regex to not split at the very start of the string but that would make it a little more difficult to understand at-a-glance, whereas the flag is very clear.

Comment: Nice one, can you tell me why you used var_export?

Comment: @Aditya to show you the resulting array, no other reason.

Comment: But there seems to be a problem with a bigger string that im taking from a text file!

Comment: Oh noes! How about asking a new question detailing your "problem" (in the form of a question) with reference to that "bigger string"? Comments aren't the place to bounce back and forth support questions (try chat).

Comment: Ok..simple i want to match three digited number follwed by a capital letter followed by anything(including a \t)? :)

Comment: I want a pony and a plastic rocket. However, here is not the right place for either of us to be sharing what we *want*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21956/discussion-between-aditya-and-salathe)

Answer (score -1):

I tried match rather than split

```
preg_match_all('/^(\d{3}.*?)*$/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Seems to get correct result for your sample